# Ldfld problems under Mac OS X / Mono, probably Mono bug

Tags: c#, .net, cil, jint

I'm using 3rd party library JInt (the JavaScript interpriter) which was working fine until I've switched to Mac OS X, after that I keep on getting ArgumentNullExceptions, after some investigation I've found out that JInt uses dynamic code generation for making some sort of  Js-Clr bridge. This method has the following instructions in the end:

```
code.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(JsUndefined).GetField("Instance");
code.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldInfo);
```

Here's how these lines are executed (Full size screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy3m3.png))

[image]

It is clearly seen that `fieldInfo` argument is not null, though when it comes to executing these lines, notice that LDFLD has no argument! (Full size screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJhXS.png)):

[image]

My current statement that will get executed is Ldnull, I performing "Step In"(Over Ldnull) and BANG exception occurs over Ldfld (Full size screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpTvd.png))::

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue you describe is a combination of different issues:

- The IL disassembly doesn't show the fields operands. It's not only for your field, you can see it in the disassembly before for a ldsfld. I'd not worry about that, I encourage you to report it has a MonoDevelop bug though.
- JInt is using a weird pattern to load a static field on the stack. I can reproduce the issue and the NRE on Mono 2.10.6 by emitting this pattern. Good news is that it is fixed in master. As you have access to JInt's code, to prevent the NRE, you can modify the else branch to simply read:

  code.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, typeof(JsUndefined).GetField("Instance"));

This will get you going.

Comment: I will submit bug report, do you know by the way where it should be submitted?

Answer (score 0):

The `ldfld` should always come with an argument, otherwise you get an invalid CLR and the runtime environment should refuse to load it (assemblies with malformed CIL throw exceptions upon loading).

I believe then that for some reason the field reference which is an argument of this `ldfld` cannot be resolved in the run time (although it exists when the code is created). On one hand this is why you get the `ldfld` without arguments in the IDE (it doesn't show the type because it is unable to load it) and on the other hand you get null exception upon executing this particular line.

Are you sure that the dynamically created assembly correctly references the assembly containing the `JsUndefined` type? The code generator could be able to see it but the does the generated code see it?

Comment: I know that ldfld should always come with an argument, I just don't know how to solve this problem... The assembly is not dynamically created, its only a method that gets created dynamically... And everything works under windows...

Comment: I see that the code loads `null` onto stack and then tries to load a field from an object. Surely loading a field from `null` will throw the null reference exception. Does it really works on Windows on the same code? Strange indeed ...

Comment: I cant see ILASM in Windows since there disassembly shows machine code compiled by JIT, though it works there like a charm. I assume the problem is not because it loads null, but instead because ldfld has no argument, such IL should never got compiled, ldfld should look like `ldfld void [JInt.Native]JsUndefined::Instance`

Comment: If the `JsUndefined::Instance` is a static field (which I don't know) then Jb Evan's answer would be true.